# Regular expression starting with letter 'c' or 'r'

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression that will check if this input starts with letters c or r then any amount of letters or numbers after that is fine here is my code so far:

```
/^c[a-zA-Z]*/
```

How would I change this allow either c or r or in capitals C or R at the beginning?

Comment: Try `/^(c|r)[a-z0-9]*$/i`.

Comment: `[crCR]` instead of `c`? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/1225328.

Comment: I get this error: Validator `^r/i[a-zA-Z]*/` is not defined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex `/^[cr][0-9a-z]*$/i` for case insensitive match:

```js
var regex = /^[cr][0-9a-z]*$/i;
console.log(regex.test('cat'));
console.log(regex.test('dog'));
console.log(regex.test('Race'));
console.log(regex.test('rat'));
console.log(regex.test('c'));
```

Comment: when i try inputting i get: Invalid regular expression: /^(/: Unterminated group

Comment: @S.Rafiq glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work `^([cC]|[rR])\w*$`

I created an online playground for you [regexr.com/3skji](http://regexr.com/3skji)

Comment: `\w` matches "\_", so it will match "c\_\_\_".

Comment: Posting a link to an answer isn't the same as posting an answer.